# Одна база данных для двух сайтов.

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется сайт на Вордпрессе с базой данных. Вопрос следующий: как я могу подключить эту базу к другому сайту? Размещены они на одном хостинге, только домены разные.

Comment: По-моему такие системы не поддерживают объединённые базы данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте ещё одного пользователя SQL, в настройках второго сайта укажите хост, имя пользователя и пароль. Более детальную информацию можно получить в службе поддержки вашего хостинга,(оператора SQL) тк для подключения со стороннего Ip(и\или аккаунта) могут потребоваться дополнительные разрешения.

Comment: То есть если я просто создам нового пользователя и пропишу его данные в настройках второго сайта то работать не будет. Заходить в админ панель будут только с одного аккаунта админа.

Comment: Я имею ввиду подключение к БД, а далее уже "в идеале"(!) у вас должны получится идентичные пользователи, админы и контент на двух сайтах.

Comment: Нового пользователя бд создавать не обязательно.
Просто пропишите на втором сайте точно такое же подключение как и на первом. Если не получится замените адрес хоста (localhost) на адрес SQL сервера первого сайта.

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных wordpress жестко прописываются ссылки на посты и медиафайлы, таким образом, если вы просто подключите существующую БД к другому, то любая ссылка одного будет вести на пост или страницу сайта-источника. Если вы хотите управлять двумя сайтами из административной панели можно воспользоваться мульти-сайтом для WP.